# How to setup this relationship and display the correct data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, models

Not sure how to set this relationship up correctly.
3 tables: Users, Posts, Statuses

Models -

```
User Model
has_many :posts

Post Model
belongs_to :user
has_one :status

Status Model
#Not sure about this.
```

Tables –

```
Users: name, email, password_digest
Posts: user_id, status_id, post_title, post_content
Statuses:  user_id, status_title, status_active
```

The user can create their own statuses, so I am not sure if the status should belong to the User or the Post.

In the Users controller, for the new action I have the following to help generate the status options in a dropdown list when making a new Post:

```
def new

@post = Post.new
@options_statuses = Status.where(:admin_user_id => session[:id])

end
```

The code to create the new Post(from within a partial):

```
<%= f.label(:status_id, "Status") %><br/>
<%= f.select(:status_id, @options_statuses.map { |s| [ s.status_title, s.id ] }) %><br/><br/>

<%= f.label(:post_title, "Title") %><br/>
<%= f.text_field(:post_title) %><br/><br/>

<%= f.label(:post_content, "Content") %><br/>
<%= f.text_area(:post_content) %><br/><br/>
```

The Post info is saved correctly to the database. The problem is when i want to show the posts via the Index or Show actions. Currently I have the following:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

<%= post.status_id %> - <%= post.created_at %><br/>  
<%= post.post_title %> - <%= post.post_content %>

<% end %>
```

Instead of showing the status_id, I would actually like to display the status_title but am not sure how to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since your Post model has a `status_id` attribute, this means Post should `belong_to :status` instead of the `has_one :status`. Status should then either `has_one :post` or `has_many :posts`.

Now, for your question: You can achieve this by delegating `title` to the associated `status` object. (Hint: think of these objects as objects here -- forget about the database behind them!) Here's how:

```
# Post model
delegate :title, to: :status, prefix: true
```

This will define a method behind the scenes that looks like this:

```
# Post model
def status_title
  status.title
end
```

For more on `delegate` see [the api docs](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate).

Comment: thanks for the info, however I am a bit confused. If Post belongs_to status, then Post would have 2 belongs_to relationships - Is this ok? I made the adjustments in the models, just wasn't sure this was allowed.

I added that line (and tried a few different variations) but am not sure how to get it to display properly. When i try to output Post.status_title I get an undefined method error for "status_title"

I also tried without the prefix and defined status_title as status.stats_title (how its stored in the db) and it does not work.

Comment: @James, yes it's perfectly fine to have 2 (or more) `belongs_to` associations in a model. This is a design concern and Rails doesn't stand in the way. Are you literally calling `Post.status_title`? Because `status_title` isn't a class method -- you need to call that method on an instance of class Post. So try `Post.first.status_title`. Or, if that doesn't work, at least make sure a Post instance can return it's associated `status` object still. If it can then the delegate should do the trick!